# what leads to the difference of sorting way in priority_queue and sort() function?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std, priority-queue

I'm learning to use `priority_queue` container and `sort()` function in the standard library and am puzzled by the parameters of compare function of `priority_queue` and `sort()` function

for the `sort()` function, my compare function: first argument < second argument will sort from smallest to greatest. *just as (1) code below*

for `priority_queue` container, my compare function: first arguemnt > second argument will sort element from smallest to greatest. *just like (2) code below*

what leads to the difference ?

this is my code of using `std::priority_queue`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Compare {
    bool operator() (int left, int right) {
    //here is left>right  .......... (1)
    return(left>right);
    }
};

template<typename T> 
void print_queue(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<int,vector<int>,Compare> q;

    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
    q.push(n);

    print_queue(q);

}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

this is my code of using `sort()`:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool compare(int i1, int i2)
{   //here is i1<i2       .............(2)
    return (i1 < i2);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] =  { 6,2,1,5,8,4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    sort(arr, arr+n, compare);

    cout << "Intervals sorted by start time : \n";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i]<<",";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,4,5,6,8
```

Comment: `std::priority_queue` simply gives the element that compares greatest first for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the c++ standard says so:

- [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order
- [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) provides lookup of the largest element (based on std::less)

So you need, to invert the comparison to obtain the same result.

Why std::priority_queue was chosen to expose the greater element, I don't know but I suspect it was inspired by section 5.2.3 of Knuth. (D. E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 3: Sorting and Searching.) as stated in the notes of [good old Stl SGI](https://www.irif.fr/~yunes/cours/cpp/stl/priority_queue.html)